# Angular custom POST action of $resource service returns 404

Tags: angularjs, post, resources

I am using angular $resource service and ran into a strange situation when I make a POST request from a custom POST action. Removing a newDb variable (see below) does make a post to Web API but data comes to Web API as null.

This is my Web API controller:

```
public class MongoDbController : ApiController
    {         
        private static List<Db> _dbs = new List<Db>
        {
            new Db {id = 1, name = "Mongo"},
            new Db {id = 2, name = "AliExpress"},
            new Db {id = 3, name = "Herbal"}
        };

        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetDbs()
        {
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _dbs.ToArray());
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            return response;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetDb(int id)
        {
            var db = _dbs.FirstOrDefault(d => d.id == id);
            if (db == null)
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, String.Format("Db with ID {0} not found", id));

            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, db);
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            return response;
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public HttpResponseMessage Put([FromBody] Db db)
        {
            var dbToUpdate = _dbs.FirstOrDefault(d => d.id == db.id);
            if (dbToUpdate == null)
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, String.Format("Db with ID {0} not found", db.id));

            dbToUpdate.name = db.name;

            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dbToUpdate);
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            return response; 
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Db db)
        {           
            var dbToCreate = new Db
            {
                id = _dbs.Count() + 1,
                name = db.name
            };

            _dbs.Add(dbToCreate);

            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dbToCreate);
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");           
            return response;           
        }        
    }
```

And the following is angular controller and factory:

```
var azMongo = angular.module('azMongo', ['services', 'ngResource']);

// ------------------- controllers ------------------------------ \\
azMongo
.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', 'dbFactory', 
    function ($scope, dbFactory) {

        $scope.id = '2';
        $scope.newDbName = 'new name';

        dbFactory.getDb({ id: $scope.id }).$promise.then(function(db) {$scope.db = db;});

        dbFactory.getDBs().$promise.then(function (dbs) { $scope.dbs = dbs;});

        $scope.addDb = function () {                       
            var newDb = new dbFactory({ id: 4, name: $scope.newDbName });

            dbFactory.saveDb(newDb, function (response) {                
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            },
            function(error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));                
            });             
        };
    }
]);

// ------------------- factories ------------------------------ \\
var services = angular.module('services', ['ngResource']);
services
.factory('dbFactory', ['$resource', 
    function ($resource) {        
        return $resource(
            'http://localhost:62820/api/mongodb/:id',            
            {},                                        
            {
                getDBs: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
                getDb: { method: 'GET' },
                saveDb: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost:62820/api/mongodb',
                    params: {},
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' }
                },
                updateDb: {method: 'PUT', url: 'http://localhost:62820/api/mongodb'}
            }
        );        
    }
]);
```

As I've mentioned, line:

```
dbFactory.saveDb(function (response) {...}
```

does work but passes no date to Web API, and an attempt to pass it like this:

```
dbFactory.saveDb(newDb, function (response) {...}
```

results in the following from error function:

```
{
   "data":"",
   "status":404,
   "config":{
      "transformRequest":[
         null
      ],
      "transformResponse":[
         null
      ],
      "method":"POST",
      "url":"http://localhost:62820/api/mongodb",
      "headers":{
         "Content-Type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
         "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"
      },
      "data":{
         "id":4,
         "name":"new name"
      }
   }
}
```

Fiddler intercepts the call and reports `{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'."}` plus it shows content type as text/html.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Took me a couple of days of banning my head against my desk until I found solution. All it takes is to add another method to a controller:

```
        [AcceptVerbs("OPTIONS")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Options()
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);            
        }
```

So the request first comes to the Options method and since it returns OK a proper PUT or POST methods gets invoked after.

I hope this post will help someone with the same issue.